# How do you change an EditText based on another EditText?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext

I have two `EditText`s. Is there a way to code the program in a way that changing one `EditText` would change the other?

For example, if chicken is 200 calories per 100 grams, then changing the `EditText` of chicken to 100 will result in an auto update of 100 grams to 50 grams, without clicking anything.

Answer (score 0):

You could install an `OnEditorActionListener` on your `EditText` and perform the action when the user stops typing:

```
myEditText.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE);

myEditText.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {

        if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {

            // call some other function to test the value and 
            // set the result on the other EditText

            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
});
```